# В чем разница между объявлениями переменных VARIABLE, DEFINE и DECLARE?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

В чем разница между объявлениями переменных?

1 Инструкция `var`:

```sql
var id number;
exec :id := 1;
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id= :id ;
```

2 и 3 `DEFINE` и `DECLARE`

```sql
DEFINE id =1;
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id= &id;

DECLARE
    v_text VARCHAR2(10); -- declare
BEGIN
    v_text := 'Hello';  --assign
    dbms_output.Put_line(v_text); --display
END;
```

http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-variables.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1.**  [var[iable]](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1014308) - это способ объявления переменных в SQL*Plus, которые должны иметь какой-либо тип из указанных в справке. Их можно использовать в sql и в pl/sql как для подстановки каких-либо значений так и для сохранения значений, например:

```
variable value varchar2(10);

begin
  select 'a'
  into :value
  from dual;
end;
/

select :value from dual
/
```

**2.**  [def[ine]](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12017.htm) - это способ объявления переменных в SQL*Plus, в которых можно указать текст, который будет подставлен вместо них в те места, где они используются. Так же [с помощью этой команды](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm#i1211130) можно получить список всех существующих переменных которые можно использовать для подстановки.

Если объявить переменную заранее и присвоить ей значение, то оно просто будет подставлено в тексте запроса:

```
define value = dual
select * from &value
/
```

Этот запрос выдаст такой результат:

```
old   1: select * from &value
new   1: select * from dual

D
-
X
```

В переменной можно указать почти любой текст:

```
define value ='23 from dual'
select 1&value
/
old   1: select 1&value
new   1: select 123 from dual

       123
----------
       123
```

Если переменной заранее не присвоить какое-либо текстовое значение, а просто использовать в тексте запроса, то SQL*Plus предложит ввести ее значение:

```
select * from &another_value
/
```

После выполнения этого текста SQL*Plus отобразит на экране просьбу указать значения для переменной:

```
Enter value for another_value:
```

Указав которое (в нашем случае `dual`) и нажав <kbd>Enter</kbd> мы увидим такой результат:

```
old   1: select * from &another_value
new   1: select * from dual

D
-
X
```

При вызове просто команды

```
define
```

Выведется примерно такой список уже существующих переменных:

```
DEFINE _DATE           = "03-AUG-15" (CHAR)
DEFINE _CONNECT_IDENTIFIER = "orcl" (CHAR)
DEFINE _USER           = "SYS" (CHAR)
DEFINE _PRIVILEGE      = "AS SYSDBA" (CHAR)
DEFINE _SQLPLUS_RELEASE = "1102000200" (CHAR)
DEFINE _EDITOR         = "Notepad" (CHAR)
DEFINE _O_VERSION      = "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options" (CHAR)
DEFINE _O_RELEASE      = "1102000200" (CHAR)
DEFINE VALUE           = "dual" (CHAR)
```

**3.**  [declare](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#i27306) - это часть объявления pl/sql блока кода `define ... begin ... end` после которой и до `begin` идет объявление [переменных](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/01_oview.htm#708), которые можно использовать внутри блока `begin ... end` Например:

```
declare
  val1 number;
  val2 varchar2(10);
  val3 date;
begin
  select 1, 'a'
  into val1, val2
  from dual;
  val3 := sysdate;
  dbms_output.put_line(val1);
  dbms_output.put_line(val2);
  dbms_output.put_line(val3);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 13):

Разница объявляемых переменных заключается в месте их применения и, соответственно, в месте хранения значений этих переменных.

- Подстановочные переменные  хоста (*host or bind  variables*) и переменные замещения (*substitute variable*) объявляются и хранятся в клиентской программе.
  Обявление переменных в клиенте зависит от клинтской программы и может несколько отличаться или вообще отсутствовать. Объявления `def[ine]` и `var[iable]` присходят от SQL*Plus, но поддерживаются также многими другими программными продуктами для работы с БД *Oracle*, например: SQL Developer, TOAD.

  1. [var[iable]](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/VARIABLE.html#GUID-B4A0DAA3-B6E0-42F7-89B0-EF9C41F02FA3) - подстановочные переменные с указанием типа данных.
     Инициализировать эти переменные возможно только в PL/SQL блоке. Могут использоваться для подстановки как входных так и выходных значений полей в DML запросах. Подстановочные переменные могут так же быть в анонимных PL/SQL блоках как для передачи так и для чтения. Подстановка переменных осуществляется на этапе подстановки (*bind*) для входных значений, или определения результата (define output) для выходных значений, непосредственно перед выполнением (*execute*).
     Важно: Подстановочные переменные не могут быть использованы для имён полей, таблиц, представлений и других объектов БД, так как они необходимы на этапе подготовки к выполнению (*parse*).
  2. [def[ine]](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/DEFINE.html#GUID-72D4998C-EC2C-4FA6-9F7F-A305C407D666) - переменные замещения. Они объявляются и сразу же инициализируются символьным значением. Все встретившиеся имена переменных с префиксом `&` будут замещены символьным значением этих переменных. Замещение произойдёт в клиенте ешё до отправки DML/DDL/DCL выражения или PL/SQL блока на выполнение серверу БД, поэтому каких либо ограничений, какая их часть может быть замещена, не существует.
- Переменные языка PL/SQL обьявляются в програмном блоке. Они не зависят от клиентской программы, так как в клиенте это только текст программы, который должен быть отправлен на сервер БД. Инициализируются переменные этого типа при выполнении програмного блока на сервере БД. Хранятся эти переменные в UGA (*user global area*) так же на сервере БД.

  3. [PL/SQL переменные](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#GUID-65F9E0D0-03CD-4C40-829A-7392ACE8F932) обьявляются в блоке после ключевого слова `declare`. В именных блоках переменные могут быть объявлены сразу после заголовка `create|alter ... is|as` объявления/изменения именного объекта. PL/SQL блоки могут содержать вложенные блоки. Зона видимости переменных ограничена блоком, в котором они объявлены. Время жизни переменных объявленых в пакетах (*packaged variables*) - сессия, во всех остальных случаях - время выполнения именного объекта или анонимного блока.

Пример исполъзующий все виды вышеописаных переменных для динамического выполнения скриптов в SQL*Plus - есть некое клолличество скриптов, но зарение неизвестно какой из них вызывать, т.е. его надо определить динамически и тут же вызвать. Все виды переменных и алиас колонки умышлено используют одно и то же имя `sqlfile`:

```
define sqlfile='default';
variable sqlfile varchar2(100);
declare
    sqlfile varchar2(100);
begin
    <<defineScript>> declare
         -- в этом блоке динамически определяем имя скрипта
         localFile constant varchar2(100) := 'my_sqlscript_01';
    begin
        sqlfile := localFile; 
    end;
    :sqlfile := sqlfile;
end;
/
column sqlfile new_value sqlfile noprint format A100;
select nvl(:sqlfile, '&sqlfile') sqlfile from dual;

host echo "prompt # &sqlfile running ..." >sql/&sqlfile\.sql
@sql/&sqlfile
```

Вывод:

```
# my_sqlscript_01 running ...
```