# Как создавать каталоги и дописывать в файл при выводе в spool?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Пишу скрипт для `sqlplus`.
Пытаюсь выводить результаты в файл. 
Делаю это так:

```
spool D:\folder\scripts.log
```

При этом, если указанный каталог не существует, то файл не записывается.

**Вопрос 1:** Можно как то заставить sqlplus создавать необходимые каталоги?

При добавлении команды `append` происходит дозапись в существующие файлы. Но если файла нет, то он и не создается.

```
spool D:\folder\scripts.log append
```

**Вопрос 2:** Можно как то создавать файл, а если он уже создан, то дозаписать в него?

Comment: Вопрос 1 - `host MD <dir>`. Вопрос 2 - файл создаётся с `append`, насколько я помню.

Comment: 1 - я попробовал просто дописать в файл скрипта. Что то пошло не так. 2 - с аппендом что то странное. Файл создается, но при следующем запуске запись в файл не идет. `spool D:\folder\scripts.log  append` сделал так.

Comment: Укоротить до воспроизводимого примера файл скрипта и добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: При воспроизведении на минимальном примере разобрался. Просто не хватало прав, о чем в консоли была соотвествующая запись, просто я ее пропустил. Оформите ответом, пожалуйста, приму ответ.

Comment: Хорошо, только вечером смогу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Короткий ответ:

1. Для создания катлогов можно использовать директиву `host command`.
2. Файл будет создан с опцией `append`, даже если он ещё не существует.

Что-бы ответ на оба вопроса выглядел убедительно, я набросал короткий скриптик:

```
set trimspool on define off head off

host cmd /c dir /b logs
spool logs/test1.log

host cmd /c if not exist logs md logs
spool logs/test1.log append
set termout off
select '1 test output' output from dual;

spool logs/test2.log
select '2 test output' output from dual;

spool logs/test1.log append
select '3 test output' output from dual;

spool off

host cmd /c dir /b logs\*.log & type logs\*.log
exit
```

И его выход я дополнил комментариями:

```
--папка ещё не существует
File Not Found 

-- и лог файл не создался
SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "logs/test1.log"

-- оба лог файлика поочерёдно создались, причём первый с append
test1.log
test2.log

logs\test1.log
1 test output
3 test output

logs\test2.log
2 test output
```

На заметку: В [ответе на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439594/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-oracle/565859#565859), который напрямую не связан с текущим, я дал пример динамического определения sql скрипта для запуска. Подобным же образом можно динамически определять все параметры для директив `spool`, `host` и т.п..