# Инициализация bind-переменной

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

Kак инициализируются bind-переменные в PL/SQL?

```
declare
 :g_control_type2 number(1);
 :ce_id number number(2);
 :result  number(1);
begin
  :g_control_type2 := null;
  :ce_id := null;
  :result := null;    
exception when others then
  raise;
end;
```

Не могу разобраться в блоке declare - то летят ошибки ora, то клиентские. Переменные - выходные и затем кладутся в т.наз. ячейки памяти.

Kак грамотно написать блок `declare` для инициализации выходных бинд-переменных?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В `declare` блоке можно объявить `pl/sql` переменные, которые могут быть инициализированы посредством bind переменных:

```
declare result varchar2(10) := :result; begin null; end;
/
```

А `bind` переменные объявляются в клиентской программе. Инициализация происходит также в клиенте и запрос к базе для этого не нужен.

В вопросе скорее всего имеется ввиду передача или возврат значений посредством `bind` переменных.  На примере с *sqlplus* это выглядит так:

```
variable result char(5); -- инициализация в null по умолчанию

exec if :result is null then :result := 'null'; else :result := 'nn'; end if; 
print result;

exec if :result = 'null' then :result := 'yes'; else :result := 'no'; end if;   
print result;
```

Вывод:

```
RESULT
------
null

RESULT
------
yes
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439594/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-oracle).