# Как использовать подстановки в скрипте

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Нужно в скрипте запрашивать данные у пользователя и использовать как имя схемы и пространства для DDL. Что я делаю неверно?

```
var :cscheme varchar(20);
var :ctspace varchar(20);

exec :cscheme := &CUR_SCH;
exec :ctspace := &CUR_TSPACE;

  CREATE TABLE :cscheme."TNABE" 
  ( 
    "V1" NUMBER, 
    "V2" NUMBER, 
    "V3" CHAR(10 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE :ctspace;
```

> Ошибка: ORA-00903: неверно имя таблицы

Comment: @MaxU А какая причина удаления ответа? Всё же было верно.

Comment: Вас больше этот вопрос не интересует? Может он был вызван опечаткой?

Comment: Интересует, скрипт рабочий. Но он неверно формирует название таблицы. Хотелось бы узнать в чем ошибка либо это не ошибка, а особенности макроподстановок.

Comment: Но @MaxU дал вам ответ и он был правильный. Вы не приняли его и не оставили комментария с замечанием.

Comment: Я повторно открыл сообщение уже после удаления ответа и не видел его

Comment: Я переработал [мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439594/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-oracle/565859#565859) в другом вопросе. Посмотрите, теперь он должен полностью отвтить на ваш вопрос. Дайте знать, если это не так и что-то осталось не понятным.